# What does Scala profile.simple._ means?

Tags: scala, import, profile

examples like:

```
import MyClass

trait MyTrait {
     this: MyClass =>
     import profile.simple_
}
```

what does the profile.simple._ mean?

I tried like this but doesn't work

```
import MyClass.profile.simple._
```

Comment: What do you mean by it doesn't work? What error message do you get?

Comment: Maybe you could add the code of your `MyClass` ?

Answer (score 0):

```
import profile.simple._
```

means to import everithing from profile.simple package, so if you have, for example, profile.simple.MyClass class you can access to it just like `new MyClass()` and you don't need to write full path `new profile.simple.MyClass()`

Answer (score 0):

When using Play with Slick (“Scala Language-Integrated Connection Kit”) it requires injecting everything from a profile into each database table and profile.simple_ is the default usually configured in a trait that's extended by DAO classes as shown at https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.4.0-M3/ScalaSlickDrivers.  According to http://slick.typesafe.com/doc/3.0.0/api/index.html#scala.slick.package$$profile$, the profile object is deprecated. However its three type members are not deprecated and each has an abstract val member named simple with type of a corresponding Driver.SimpleQL that is "a collection of values for using the query language with a single import statement."